# Running an Rscript command on Linux with a R file that contains whitespaces int eh name?

Tags: r, linux, rscript

I currently am trying to run:

```
Rscript My Simulation From Jan 25.R
```

which gives me errors. My working directory is inside where the file

`"My Simulation From Jan 25.R"`

is held. I have tried various things, like:

1) "My Simulation From Jan 25.R"

2) "My\ Simulation\ From\ Jan\ 25.R"

3) $"My Simulation From Jan 25.R"

to no avail. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Can you not rename your files and folders? Wouldn't it be easier? In general, having spaces in file names and folder is not recommended

Comment: Try single quotes around your R file. 
i.e
`Rscript 'My Simulation From Jan 25.R'`

Comment: @Tung Unfortunately I am in a system where they only allow execution but not renaming of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two notes:

1) Both single and double quotes should work.

2) Make sure that you run the command in the same directory where the file is located.

[image: Results from a test run]